# Handling Error 3021 (EOF) VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare two tables by using a serial number as the primary key. Since they can vary in sizes a serial number may be in SerialAccount_b, and not in SerialAccount_a. When this happens, I get to the end of file since one recordset advances while the other stays put in an attempt to find the serial. It then returns Error 3021. I have it error handling, but I want the code to resume to comparing the rest of the data after this happens, and I am having trouble doing so. If you could help me out that would be great. If you have any other suggestions on how to improve this subprogram that would be good too.

```
Public Sub compareSerialAccount()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstA As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstB As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstFiltered As DAO.Recordset
Dim serialNumber As String
On Error GoTo HandleErrors

Set dbs = CurrentDb
counter1 = 0
' Opens the recordsets of SerialAccount_a and _b in
' preperation for comparison of data
Set rstA = dbs.OpenRecordset("SerialAccount_a", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstB = dbs.OpenRecordset("SerialAccount_b", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rstB.EOF

Do Until rstA.EOF
    If rstA.Fields("serial") = rstB.Fields("serial") Then
        If rstA.Fields("accountnumber") <> rstB.Fields("accountnumber") Then
            ' Print message
            counterForMessage = counterForMessage + 1
        End If
        If rstA.Fields("model_number") <> rstB.Fields("model_number") Then
            ' Print message
            counterForMessage = counterForMessage + 1
        End If
    Else
    ' This will always be the default until there are two matching serial numbers
    ' This will advnace rstA +1 and make rstFiltered stay put
    ' I had to work around the advancements on the outside of this statement
    ' Thats why I move rstA (+1 = 1) and rstFiltered (-1 +1 = 0)
        rstB.MoveNext
        rstA.MovePrevious
    End If
    rstA.MoveNext
Loop
rstB.MoveNext
Loop

If counterForMessage = 0 Then
Debug.Print "| There are no discrepancies between SerialAccount_a and SerialAccount_b!                                 |"
End If

HandleErrors:
Select Case Err.Number

    Case 3021
    serialNumberForError = rstA.Fields("serial")
    Debug.Print "| Serial number " & serialNumberForError & " was either added or deleted."
    Resume Next

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you are doing it in this way. You could create queries in Access, even using the **Find Unmatched Query Wizard**. This will find those records in one table that are not in another table. You can create two of these if you also wish to find those in the second table that are not in the first.

If you wish to do this programmatically, then borrow the SQL statement that the Wizard creates, and study [table-joins](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx).

**Added** In response to comment:
You are opening recordsets based on the table-names. These contain all of the data from each table. You can instead use a SQL statement that only retrieves data (from rows) where a value in one field of a table does not appear in a field of the other table, plus any other criteria that you need. You can loop through the resultant recordset in the same way you are now, but the recordset will only contain the rows that you are interested in. You can check the `RecordCount` to confirm if any records at all were retrieved.

Comment: The code works. It's just handling that error. Using SQL would not help me because I would not be able to use the data like I am now because it returns just rows. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: I've added to my answer. You seem to have skipped a bit in your database studies: SQL statements, table joins, criteria (WHERE clauses). Looping through entire tables and testing each row is rarely (if ever) necessary.